# Ūtāturne linguā Latīnā aliquis adverbō «ferē» velut linguā Anglicā verbō «almost» ūtimur?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation, adjective, adverb

Linguā Anglicā, saepe cum multīs adverbīs atque adiectīvīs, plūrima quōrum significātiōnēs absolūtās habent (exempla sunt *«always»* vel *«everything»* vel *«nothing»* vel *«never»*, et cētera), adverbō *«almost»* ūtimur ut significēmus adverbum vel adiectīvum nōn ferre subtīlem, sed significātiōnem quae propē principālem est. Exempla:

- *«almost always»*
- *«almost everything»*
- *«almost nothing»*
- *«almost never»*

Ūtāmurne linguā Latīnā verbō *ferē* eōdem modō (exempla *ferē nihil* vel *ferē semper*, et cētera) ut linguā Anglicā, aut aliō?

Sī male Latīnē scrīpsī, apologiās vōbīs agō.

Comment: FWIW, L&S lists a pair of examples of the word [paene](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpaene) modifying adjectives as you ask: totidem paene, cuncta paene. Both in Cicero.

Comment: A quick peek in OLD does indeed show examples of fer(m)e used with semper, nihil, numquam, and omnia. It not infrequently follows the word that it qualifies.

Comment: Alternatively,  Isidore gives two examples of the comparative for English '-ish.' One is Elder *Senior* which he says is somebody less old than *Senex.* Adv. *saepiuscule* is given as fairly often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ita est, saltem in Latina post-mediaevali, ubi saepe hoc verbum "fere" in sensu indicato invenitur. Verum quoque est quod cnread dixit, hoc verbum scil. frequenter (etsi non semper) non ante, sed post verbum quod modificat poni. Alia verba idem fere significantia sunt "paene" ("paene dixi" "I almost said"), "prope" ("prope nihil" "nearly nothing"), et "propemodo" ("propemodo nemo" "hardly anybody").